# REACT JS class Lifecycles: How to put http request in ComponentdidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a http request to call once the `prop` taken from redux store updates as shown below:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state.queryBuild);
  return {
      queryBuilderObject: state.queryBuild,
  }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SummaryView);
```

Here is my `componentdidupdate` function:

```
async componentDidUpdate()
  {
    //console.log("Component unmount detected");
    //console.log(this.props.queryBuilderObject);
    this.setState({state: {
      ...this.state,
      isLoading: true,
    }});
    await axios.post(ApiEndPoints.getSummaryDataByQueryBuilder,this.props.queryBuilderObject,{timeout: axiosTimeOut})
    .then(response => {
      console.log("REsponse:");
      console.log(response);
          this.setState({state: {
            ...this.state,
            isLoading: false,
          }});
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error.message));


  }
```

now here's the problem... somehow I want to only make an http request if `props.queryBuilderObject` changes that comes from redux store. But when I am going this way, I am entering into an infinite loop as I am setting state and hence componentdidupdate is triggered everytime.

Can someone suggest the right way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` receives the previous props and state as arguments, you can check the previous props' `queryBuilderObject` against the current props' `queryBuilderObject` and if they are not equal do the POST request.

[componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> You **may call `setState()` immediately** in `componentDidUpdate()` but note
> that **it must be wrapped in a condition**

If you update state from this lifecycle function without a conditional check then it will likely cause infinite render looping.

There is also no need to spread in existing state in the `setState` function; `setState` does a shallow merge of state updates.

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.queryBuilderObject !== this.props.queryBuilderObject) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    await axios
      .post(
        ApiEndPoints.getSummaryDataByQueryBuilder,
        this.props.queryBuilderObject,
        { timeout: axiosTimeOut }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error: " + error.message));
  }
}
```

Comment: wow brother, i exactly needed what you just posted... thanks so much this helps a lot!